# react context in another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, screen, provider

Good evening everyone,
I created two screens and I would like to pass the context to one of this screen but it doesn't work.
Here what I have so far :

App :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import ExpenseScreen from "./src/screens/ExpenseScreen";
import BalanceScreen from "./src/screens/BalanceScreen";
import {ExpenseProvider} from "./src/context/ExpenseContext";

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home:HomeScreen,
    Expense:ExpenseScreen,
    Balance: BalanceScreen
  }, 
  {
    initialRouteName:"Home",
    defaultNavigationOptions:{
      title:"App",
    }
  }
)

const App = createAppContainer(navigator);
export default () => {
  return <ExpenseProvider>
            <App/>
          </ExpenseProvider>
};
```

HomeScreen:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button} from "react-native";

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
 
  return(
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>HomeScreen</Text>

        {/*Shows default display*/}
        
        <Button
          onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Expense')}
          title="Expense Tracker"
          />
        
    
          <Button 
          onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Balance')}
          title="Balance"
        />

    </View>
  ) 
}; 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
      fontSize: 30
    }
  });
  
  export default HomeScreen;
```

Provider :

```
import React from 'react';

const ExpenseContext = React.createContext();

export const ExpenseProvider = ({children}) => {
    const expensePosts = [
        {title: 'Expense Post #1'},
        {title: 'Expense Post #2'},
        {title: 'Expense Post #3'}
    ]

    return <ExpenseContext.Provider value={expensePosts}>{children}</ExpenseContext.Provider>
};

export default ExpenseContext;
```

Screen :

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button, Flatlist } from "react-native";
import ExpenseContext from '../context/ExpenseContext';


const ExpenseScreen = () => {
  const expensePosts = useContext(ExpenseContext)

  return(
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Expense Tracker</Text>  
        <Flatlist
          data={expensePosts}
          keyExtractor={(expensePost) => expensePost.title}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          }}
        
        />      
    </View>
  ) 
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
      fontSize: 30
    }
  });
  
  export default ExpenseScreen;
```

I am trying to import the context into the "expenseScreen" but it doesn't work.
The error message I have is " element type is invalid: expected a string or a class but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in or you might have mixed up default and name imports. Check the render method of 'ExpenseScreen'".

What am I missing ?
Does the Expenseprovider exported in the App only applies for the 'homeScreen' ?
Thank you very much in advance and hope this is clear enough.

Comment: @Kartikey Fixing indentations and grammar is one thing, editing the OP's code is another. Please do try to leave the code as-is as this is perfectly reviewable.

Comment: What is the issue or error, or what specifically isn't working? Please provide more details and context.

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the code. My ExpenseScreen is accessible from the HomeScreen via a button to navigate there. So maybe the issue comes from here.

Comment: The provider only needs to wrap the `App` and any component under this sub-tree can access the context value. Nothing overt seems to be an issue. Could you try creating an [Expo Snack](https://expo.dev/) of your code that (*hopefully*) reproduces the issue for use to inspect and debug live? If anything you may find the issue when distilling your code down to a minimal example.

Comment: @DrewReese, thank you for the tips!